# notifyDataSetChanged() not refreshing expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview, notifydatasetchanged

I am using `Expandable ListView` and the data in it is populated through `Sqlite` database. I have given an option to delete a group from `ExpandableListView` and it actually deletes the respective `row` in the database. **But the activity doesn't gets refreshed and the deleted 'case' is visible until one goes back and comes again to this `activity`.** 
I have created a `class` that `extends *BaseExpandableListAdapter*`. It contains all the `overridden` methods. Following is the code:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapterForRunning extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
public  static List<String> _listDate;
public int index;
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapterForRunning(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData,int i,List<String> listDate) {
     this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    this.index=i;
    this._listDate=listDate;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

//other overridden methods
}
```

Now there is another `class` `RunningCase.java` which `extends Activity`. This `class` is used to populate the data in `ExpandableListView`. `OnLongClick()` (tap and hold) of any group in `ExpandableListView`, a `context menu` appears. The `context menu` contains an option **Delete** to delete that case from the database and refresh the `RunningCase activity`.

```
    public class RunningCase extends Activity

    {
    String[] day;
    LinearLayout layout_MainMenu;
    Case cases;
    ExpandableListAdapterForRunning listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    List<String> listDate;
     HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;    
    Case date;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    prepareListData();     
    expListView=(ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    listAdapter= new  ExpandableListAdapterForRunning(this,listDataHeader,listDataChild,i,listDate);
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(expListView);
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add("Delete");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    final DatabaseHandler dbs = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Cursor c = null;
    ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();

    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);

    if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
          String cp=(String) listAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, 0);
        caseno=cp.substring(11, cp.length());       
        }

    if(item.getTitle()=="Delete")
    {       
        dbs.deletecase(caseno);
        expListView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  //this is not working
            }
        });
        Toast.makeText(this, "The Case has been Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 return true;
}
//this is the method to populate the expandableListView
public void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDate =new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    List<Case> cases = db.getRunning();       
    int i=0;
    for (Case cn : cases) {
        String str = cn.getPetitioner()+" V/S " + cn.getDefendant();
        String caseNo=cn.getCaseNumber();
        String caseStage=cn.getCaseStage();
        String caseName=cn.getCourtName();
        listDataHeader.add(str);
        List<String> case2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        case2.add("Case No. : "+caseNo);
        case2.add("Court Name :"+caseName);
        case2.add("Case Stage :"+caseStage);

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i++), case2);

    }
       List<Date> date = db.getRunning_child();       
       for (Date cn : date) {
           String str = cn.getNextDate();
           listDate.add(str);
    }
}
```

The methods `db.getRunning()`, `db.getRunning_child()` retrieve data from database.
Also, the following is the code to delete the case from database which is working perfectly:

```
void deletecase(String casenum){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String whereClause = "Case_number = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
            casenum
        };

    db.delete(TABLE_CASEINFO,whereClause,whereArgs);        
    db.delete(TABLE_CLIENTINFO,whereClause,whereArgs);      
    db.delete(TABLE_DATEINFO,whereClause,whereArgs);        
        Log.d("case deleted","casenum: "+casenum); 

    db.close(); // Closing database connection      
}
```

Please help me out. The `activity` should get refreshed on deleting a case so that the deleted case no more appears.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you remove the entry from DB but you don't remove it from list. you should modify your long click routine

Comment: How should i remove it from the list? Can you please help me with the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before calling `notfifyDataSetChanged` you should update your data which are private HashMap> _listDataChild by `setData` method which is created by you on your adapter. First set data, then notify.

Example:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public MyAdapter(...) {
    super(...);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    .....
    return view;

}

private void setData() {
    ...
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: That means I should call the method **prepareListData()** before calling **notifyDataSetChanged()** ?

Comment: @ankul09jain I don't think so. You should update the data in your adapter. When the first time you create your adapter instance, you send some data to your adapter by constructor. **prepareListData()** can't update it.

Comment: Thanks @MSr. I added the following lines before calling notifyDataSetChanged() and it worked:        listDataHeader.remove(groupPosition);    
      listDate.remove(groupPosition);
      for(int j=0;j<listDataHeader.size();j++)
            listDataChild.remove(listDataHeader.get(j));

Comment: Adding the above lines of code works for the first time. But as I delete another case continuously then there occurs a **NullPoiinterException** at getChildPosition() under getChild() method of ExpandableListAdapterForRunning.java. Please tell me where am I going wrong